# How to assign new browser instance to WinFormBorwserView

Tags: c#, winforms, dotnetbrowser

I'm Trying to create new instance of a `DotNetBrowser` and assign it to my panel inside windows forms.

Based on `DotNetBrowser` start guide, to create new instance of browser (that have its own cache, etc) I need to do following:

```
   BrowserContextParams params1 = new BrowserContextParams("C:\\my-data1");
   BrowserContext context1 = new BrowserContext(params1);
   Browser browser1 = BrowserFactory.Create(context1);
```

My question is, what do I do with this browser now?
I want to asign it to my browserpanel like this

```
   browserpanel.Controls.Add(browser1);
```

But this will not work because I need to have object of a class
**WinFormsBrowserView** to assign it to browserpanel. And If I create object of a type WinFormsBrowserView, I cant customize it as documentation explains.
And the Browser inside newly constructed **WinFormsBrowserView** is readonly, so i cant assign this browser to it.

Comment: its casting on browserView.. and I created only Browser Interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution:

```
BrowserContextParams params1 = new BrowserContextParams("C:\\my-data1");
context1 = new BrowserContext(params1);
browser1 = BrowserFactory.Create(context1);
WinFormsBrowserView  browserview = new WinFormsBrowserView(browser1);
```